# File/Disk Recover Mac Book

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, recovery

How can I recover lost, erased, files from Hard disk bad shut-down. Free apps only please. MacBook.I had a bad shut down, then restarted system. I lost bunch of docs, pics, music

Comment: I’ll see if there is a better duplicate for file recovery. Keep in mind, we don’t host shopping questions so when you restrict an option to free, that’s shopping. Asking about functions or how to select software that can do a function is fine.

Comment: This thread has some useful information - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21953/options-for-recovering-deleted-files

Comment: thanks mike, your a big help. this question may have been asked before. Not by me and I haven't seen an answer from previous question.

Comment: Start with data rescue. They let you perform the entire recovery for free and then test a couple files to be sure they have usable files. It is paid software if you need many files back.